# Views - "Add no results behavior" not doing what I would like it to

Tags: views

I've selected a "Add no results behavior" option for my Views page which consists of a search form. The problem with the "Add no results behavior" feature is that it displays by default, even before I've attempted to do a search. How do I change this so that it only displays AFTER the user has attempted to do a search (for which there are no results)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using Views 3, on the Views config page under `Exposed form`, change `Exposed form style` from `Basic` to `Input required`. Optionally change the other related settings on this page. Apply the settings and save the View and it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you @enzipher
Is there by any chance a way to make the export buttons (csv, xls) to only display when there ARE search results? At the moment they display whether or not there are search results...

Comment: Glad to help. I am afraid I don't know what "Export buttons" your are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was the Views Data Export module. @enzipher

Comment: @kine456 I don't know where those shows up, so I don't think I can help you with that. I would suggest you ask another question for that.